# Present perfect, since something has "NOT" been Happening/Heppened

Tags: present-perfect, negation, since

I was wondering if this form of present perfect is correct:

It's been 257 days since the last day a cat video on the internet has not made me cry!

My main concern is with the negative second part. So, the question is, which one is correct:

It's been 257 days since the last day a cat video on the internet hasn't made me cry!
It's been 257 days since the last day a cat video on the internet didn't make me cry!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you have cried at a cat video _every day_ for 257 days? If not, you should say "It's been 257 days since [the last day] a cat video on the internet made me cry." _It's been a week since X happened_ means that X has not happened again in the past week.

Comment: I mean to say, "Not Crying" has "not" happened for 257 days straight. Meaning, I've been crying everyday for 257 days!! And also today.

Comment: In other words, the last day that I haven't cried/didn't cry (there's another similar question!), was 258 days ago.

Comment: Perhaps add your clarification into the question as not everyone reads the comments.

Comment: OK, if you really did mean that, it's a rather confusing way of saying so. The construction "It's been... since..." is usually used when something _hasn't_ been happening. Why not say "I've cried at a cat video on every one of the past 257 days", or similar?

Comment: Huh, yes, I see. I actually noticed that if I neglect the "negative" aspect of the question, the answer becomes very clear:
It's been 257 days since the last day a cat video on the internet has made me cry!
It's been 257 days since the last day a cat video on the internet made me cry!
Both of which are correct.

Comment: So, I guess the answer is, grammatically, both are correct, but, nobody talks like that!!!